# summing the variables in tibble using tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse

How to transform the following input by treating TRUE condition as '1' and sum that count for each variable in db. if it is FALSE it would be zero.

input

```
db  type1 type2
t1  TRUE FALSE
t1  TRUE FALSE
t1  TRUE FALSE
t2  TRUE FALSE
t3  FALSE TRUE
t3  FALSE TRUE
```

output

```
db  type1 type2
t1  3 0
t2  1 0
t3  0 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sum` function in R treats TRUE as 1, FALSE as 0, so it's simply:

```
df %>% group_by(db) %>% summarize_all(sum)

# A tibble: 3 x 3
#      db type1 type2
#  <fctr> <int> <int>
#1     t1     3     0
#2     t2     1     0
#3     t3     0     2
```

`summarize_all` summarize all columns except the group variable.